# Laravel 9 - 404 error on welcome.blade.php file

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-9

I have created a new laravel project as i always do and for some reason the default welcome page isnt loading and shows the error message `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

I have searched for other answers which all give examples of what to put into your .htaccess file but mine already has the code examples i have seen inside it. Thank you in advance

Web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

The `welcome.blade.php` has the default code for the laravel welcome page

My htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure the welcome.blade.php file exists?

Comment: How do you serve your project? Anything useful in the laravel.log?

Comment: Yes the welcome.blade.php is in views by default.

Comment: Sorry brombeer what do you mean by serve? I am new to Laravel and PHP

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve` or a "regular" webserver like Apache or nginx?